# Converting date from string to date format with "/" as a date separator

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to convert a date

```
"16/12/2021"
```

from a string to actual date format "DD-MM-YYYY" or "YYYY-MM-DD" in Pyspark
i have tried multiple ways of doing it including the below

```
df.select(to_date(datecol,"DD-MM-YYYY"))
```

And Also

```
date_format(to_timestamp(mydate,'16/12/2021'))
```

i am getting the same result for any method i use and the result is a Null value.

If i change the source date from the above to the below

```
"2022-12-16"
```

i get the conversion correct using any method.

any help with converting the date with "/" and dd/mm/yyyy format to a correct date format please ?

Thanks

Comment: I need a dynamic approach so whatever the string format is, it should be converted to a valid date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a general solution, you need a round trip from string to date, and then from date back to string.

```py
date_format(to_date(datecol, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```